# Finding source of vps memory spike (lemonstand)

Tags: php

Im running lemonstand which is a php based ecommerce software on a dreamhost vps.

About once or twice a week I get an email that my vps went more than 10% over its memory allocation and it is being automatically rebooted.

How do I find the source of this memory spike? I was trying to get newrelic installed to try and hunt it down, but it apparently didnt install correctly when I did the install command via ssh and well, I just dont know where to go next with it.

Is there another application or another way to hunt down the source of my memory spike?